# pattern after match

Tags: sed

```
$string = "http://192.168.0.1/?url=http://www.google.com/?hl=";
```

how to return only

```
http://www.google.com/?hl=
```

by use linux command

Comment: I'm voting you up cause I like your question. Has alot of symbols lol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your test string is truly in a shell variable named `string` then its as easy as this:

```
$ string="http://192.168.0.1/?url=http://www.google.com/?hl="
$ echo ${string#*=}
http://www.google.com/?hl=
```

If you really intend to use a *unix command* then I would suggest either `perl` or `sed`.  Perl has the advantage of being able to use the non-greedy qualifier.

#### With `perl`

```
$ echo "http://192.168.0.1/?url=http://www.google.com/?hl=" | perl -pe 's/.*?=//'
http://www.google.com/?hl=
```

#### With `sed`

```
$ echo "http://192.168.0.1/?url=http://www.google.com/?hl=" | sed 's/[^=]*=//'
http://www.google.com/?hl=
```